# How to sync two Wordpress sites, while maintaining some differences between them

Tags: virtualhost, wordpress, ubuntu-14.04, synchronization, apache2

I have an Ubuntu Linux VM that is hosting about 105 Wordpress sites. For each of the sites on my server, I have a "clone" version of the site (ie www.example.com and clone.example.com). The clone version for each website on my server is used for my Google Adwords campaigns.

Each clone/adwords site is exactly the same as the master version of the site, except for the phone number & a few other minor details tweaked for Google Adwords.

Now for what I am trying to do:

I would like to be able to sync each master and clone/adwords site everyday so that the content on each (master & clone) site matches.

However, I would like to keep the minor differences on the adwords clone site like the phone #, and the adwords pieces.

Is there any way to sync a master and clone while keeping a minor difference like phone number on the clone site intact?

Or would I have to sync master and clone site & go back in to the clone site & update the phone number every time I sync? - This makes syncing them daily a bit impractical, considering the number of websites that I would have to update & the number of places on each clone site that I would need to switch back the phone number.

Any suggestions will be greatly appreciated!

Comment: I don't understand. Why don't you just have one version of the websites that is optimized for Google Adwords?

Comment: There are multiple reasons for my having a different version of the site for ad campaigns, but too much to go into & off topic.basically comes down to: that is how the company I work for wants it lol

Answer (score 0):

The old-school way to approach this would be placing the site-specific details into code snippets in a different subfolder, or a CSS template, that is excluded from the sync.  CSS would likely be the most efficient method, since you're not wanting large differences, just a few lines of text here and there.

Answer (score -3):

You didn't write how you clone your main site.
But assuming you use wp-cli you could do it using [this howto](https://halfelf.org/2014/migrating-with-wp-cli/) and add sed/perl/whatever script in between the export and import step to change the phone number.